# ¿Puede corromperse una variable numérica estática?

Tags: hilos, rust

¿Es posible que la última línea muestre cualquier número otro además de `1337` o `0` debido a una condición de carrera?

```
static mut FOO: i32 = 1337;
// en hilo 1
unsafe { FOO = 0; }
// en hilo 2
unsafe { println!("{}", FOO); }
```

Imagino que `FOO` podría leerse mientras se escribe, cuando sólo se han actualizado algunos bits, si las operaciones se realizan en diferentes hilos.

Comment: En Rust ni idea, pero otros lenguajes compilados **no garantizan la atomicidad** en operaciones de acceso a memoria. En otras palabras, va a depender de la arquitectura de la CPU y del tipo de dato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí es posible. Siempre que se trabaja con multithreading, es recomendable utilizar Atomic.

```
static mut FOO: AtomicI32 = AtomicI32::new(5);

fn main() {

    unsafe { 
        FOO = AtomicI32::new(50);
    }
    unsafe {
        println!("{}", *FOO.get_mut());
    }
}
```

[Rust doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/index.html)